# Compare structured and unstructured postal addresses

Tags: string, location, string-comparison

I have a list of unstructured postal address strings and structured postal address strings.
What should I use to compare these?

Example addresses:

```
Unstructured: john appartments 7 koramangala bangalore india 560066
structured:   7, john appartments, koramangala, bangalore-560066, india
```

Comment: What language? Also: can you provide some example addresses / test cases that demonstrate the problem in practice? Right now the question is too broad and generic.

Comment: Any language is fine. I just want an appropriate algorithm to do this.

Comment: Ok. Can you provide example address formats that you wish to compare?

Comment: Added in the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you are limited to finding the likelihood of these strings being similar then you need to look into techniques mentioned here [Finding groups of similar strings in a large set of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329297/finding-groups-of-similar-strings-in-a-large-set-of-strings)

Another approach - if you have access to maps/dictionaries then you can "structurize" any address (by finding the name of the country, postal code, street name, etc.) and then compare.

Good luck