# Algorithm for grouping millions of names into groups of similar names

Tags: python, algorithm, grouping

I want to group the names in a list of a few million names into groups of similar names. For example, if the names "John", "John12" and "azJohn" appear in the list, they should all go into the same grouo. A naive approach could be to use an algorithm like this:

```py
import Levenshtein

def group_similar_names(names, threshold=2):
    groups = {}
    for name in names:
        for group_name, group_list in groups.items():
            if Levenshtein.distance(name, group_name) <= threshold:
                group_list.append(name)
                break
        else:
            groups[name] = [name]
    return groups.values()
```

Alas, this algorithm does not scale for a dataset with million of names.

Can anyone come up with an algorithm that works for a dataset with millions of names? The algorithm may be implemented in any language. It is fine for the algorithm to put the same name into multiple groups, but preferably it would only put the name into the group(s) in which the name matches best.

Comment: Would the ‘same’ name in [various languages](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Translations_of_male_given_names_in_multiple_languages) classify as belonging to the same group? What is the requirement for two names to be in a group?

Comment: Seems easy, but I doubt there's a computationally efficient answer. A human can easily identify `John123`, `coolJohn`, `nhoj`, and `j0hn` as all belonging to the `John` group. Something like Levenshtein distance doesn't help at all.

Comment: I can't give you a precise definition of "same". I would need to determine experimentally what yields the best results. The use-case to group a list of usernames into groups of similar usernames. Note that the usernames may not necessarily be based on names given to people in real life.

Comment: Maybe try a large language model like ChatGPT? You can train it on your own dataset.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [Soundex](https://pypi.org/project/soundex/) library to compute a phonetic signature for every name. The signature is a four-character string. This can be used as group index. All names with the same signature are assigned to the same group.

As a preprocessing step, you could remove digits or special characters from the names. To spare the signature calculation for very frequent names like John, you could use a dictionary to find their group. Only if a name is not present in this dictionary, the signature is calculated.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55500422/1911064) is a related answer which refers to the commonly used term *fuzzy matching*.